# Effectively measure the available screen

Tags: android, dimensions

I need to find a way to actually get the dimensions of the screen of my device. I've been trying for long time now and there I cannot find a way to find the height and width in pixel of the drawable screen.

Here is the code I'm using right now:

SCREEN_HEIGHT = metrics.heightPixels - unusable_height;

Where unusable_height is found by:

```
    //Calculate action Bar Height
    if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)){
        unusable_height = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }

    //Calculate the navigation bar height
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        unusable_height = unusable_height + getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
```

This works pefectly in my tablet however in my phone the resulting screen height is too large as stuff gets drawn off the screen. (And I calculate all my sizes according to the screen height). This is in landscape mode.

Any help? How can I know the total number of pixels from the end of the action bar to where I can't draw anymore.?

In my phone the navigation bar doesn't rotate so it stays where the bottom would be in portrait mode. So the bottom is the end of the screen. However in my tablet the navigation bar rotates and is put at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Are you using the support ActionBar from AppCompat? or Actionbar Sherlock?

Comment: Its not sherlock since i ve never downloaded the library. So I assume is the one appcompat.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to bypass the problem. However it is not neat. I'm posting it here in case anyone else needs it. It is possible to get the width and height by getting those variables form a layout or view whose LayoutParams were set both to MATCHPARENT. Of course this view needs to be that is set to setContentsView, so it should be like the master layout. However this will thrown non-zero values only when the view is already drawn, which means that you can't get its values in methods like on onCreate or onResume.

On the plus side, it should allways work and it is very simple.